# youtube api v3 credentials expire after 1 hour during upload (objective-c)?

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api, access-token

My upload stopped after 1 hour due to invalid credential. Should I call `authorizeRequest` on the tickets manually before token expiry? Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the video is quite big enough because it's taking more than 1 hour, and I recommend resumable upload for it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzXWnuzxNDQ
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

Unfortunately we can't extend epiration term of OAuth2.0 credentials, so as you say, you have to refresh your credentials with your refresh token.

Comment: resumable upload did not work, I received repeating invalid credential errors immediately. Looks like I have to update the token before expiry.

Answer (score 0):

This 1-hour limitation is a known issue in our side. You can follow [this issue tracker ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5124) to get notified when it's fixed.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5124